# i have already tried,but i don't no how to call the function in another file

Tags: node.js

sir/madam exlain the flow of node.js from client to server with the dynamic parameters passing from userinterface to api's based up on these parameters we will get the output from api.for example sabre api etc..

```
exports.flightDestinations = function(req, res) {
    var callback = function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            // Your error handling here
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            // Your success handling here
            // console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            res.send(JSON.parse(data));

        }
    };

    sabre_dev_studio_flight.airports_top_destinations_lookup({
        topdestinations: '50'
    }, callback);
};
```

we want this value 50 from user...and how to give this value?and how to call this function in node.js.

Comment: In general terms `Client` and `server` communicate with each other over network ( generally internet ). In case of web services this communication protocol is HTTP and the communication is done via HTTP requests and responses. So... you will have to send a HTTP request to server. You probably need to read about something like `Ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

The exports variable is initially set to that same object (i.e. it's a shorthand "alias"), so in the module code you would usually write something like this:

```
var myFunc1 = function() { ... };
var myFunc2 = function() { ... };
exports.myFunc1 = myFunc1;
exports.myFunc2 = myFunc2;
```

to export (or "expose") the internally scoped functions myFunc1 and myFunc2.

And in the calling code you would use:

```
var m = require('mymodule');
m.myFunc1();
```

where the last line shows how the result of require is (usually) just a plain object whose properties may be accessed.

NB: if you overwrite exports then it will no longer refer to module.exports. So if you wish to assign a new object (or a function reference) to exports then you should also assign that new object to module.exports

It's worth noting that the name added to the exports object does not have to be the same as the module's internally scoped name for the value that you're adding, so you could have:

```
var myVeryLongInternalName = function() { ... };
exports.shortName = myVeryLongInternalName;
// add other objects, functions, as required
```

followed by:

```
var m = require('mymodule');
m.shortName(); // invokes module.myVeryLongInternalName
```